# Android Recycler view disable the scrollbar but not use setVerticalScrollBarEnabled

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, scrollbar

I have a view pager and have 3 fragments. These 3 fragments are recycler view.

I would like to when I drag to the next page, the scroll bar will be disappeared. But I don't want to use `setVerticalScrollBarEnabled`. Because when called this method, the main content items will be scaled up. I think the reason is the scroll bar width is 4dp. So the main content items will be scaled up. I don't like this scale up effect.

I also tried `setVerticalScrollbarThumbDrawable` with transparent colour. But this method need to add this condition `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q`.

Anybody can give me some suggestions. Thanks a lot.

```
public void SetRecyclerViewScrollBar(boolean enable) {
        if(this.mRecyclerView != null) {
            this.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                if(!enable) {
                    this.mRecyclerView.setVerticalScrollbarThumbDrawable(this.mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.scrollbar_transparent));
                    this.mRecyclerView.setVerticalScrollbarTrackDrawable(this.mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.vertical_scrollview_track_transparent));
                } else {
                    this.mRecyclerView.setVerticalScrollbarThumbDrawable(this.mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.scrollbar));
                    this.mRecyclerView.setVerticalScrollbarTrackDrawable(this.mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.vertical_scrollview_track));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show me your code

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make some semi transparent scroll thumb drawable and add this:

```
android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
```

or Java/Kotlin side:

```
scrollableView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

this will make your thumb won't take space and will be drawn on top of your list/content. check out this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMI7J.png) how different styles behaves. and then you may use `setVerticalScrollBarEnabled`, space for your content (whole screen width) won't change and won't be redrawn (thus scaled up)

Comment: do you know why I called `setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false)` but not affect immediately. But I called the `this.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` before `setVerticalScrollBarEnabled `. It will affect immediately

Comment: `setVerticalScrollBarEnabled` should force layout to be redrawn, just like `notifyDataSetChanged` makes all list items redraw (adapters job). you can try to `scrollableView.invalidate()` or `scrollbable.requestLayout()` call just after `setVerticalScrollBarEnabled` to force parent layout to be redrawn (hide/show scrollbars). still I'm also suprised that setting scrollbars visibility doesn't work immediatelly...

Answer (score 1):

If it's not important show scrollbar try to add this in your XML it will disappear scrollbar

```
 android:scrollbars="none"
```

Comment: is very important

Answer (score 0):

Try use this in your layout file.

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

It should be like this.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:scrollbars="none"
     ...
```

Comment: I need to hide the scroll bar when my condition is reached

Comment: find “mRecyclerView” id.It should be in your “XXX.xml” file

Comment: it will be made the scroll bar hide when the view is created